# Laravel dropdown gets all options even if not selected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have drop-down where i show my products attributes, and **no matter if i select any option or not it will add all the options to my cart** under selected product.

what i need is to just get selected options or leave it empty if nothing has selected.

here is my blade code:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($options as $optiontitle => $optioncollection)
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $optiontitle }}</td>
    <td class="text-left">
      <select name="attr" class="form-control">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       @foreach($optioncollection as $suboption)
         <option value="{{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}</option>
       @endforeach
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

here is my controller method for `attributes` which i call them `option`

```
$options = $product->suboptions->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
  return [$item->option->title => $item];
});
```

and this is my cart method where thing happen and everything will be add to cart instead of selected only.

```
public function addingItem(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $product = Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

      $customAttributes = [];
      if(!empty($product->suboptions)){
          foreach($product->suboptions as $subs) {
              array_push($customAttributes, [
                  'attr' => [
                      'label' => $subs->title,
                      'price' => $subs->price,
                  ]
              ]);
          }
      }
      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $customAttributes,
      ));
      Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## UPDATE

What I need to get is options `title` and `price` (take a look at my order sample to see why and where I need those)

```
"[{\"id\":29,\"name\":\"effewf\",\"price\":24524,\"quantity\":1,\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Gray\",\"price\":\"7000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Red\",\"price\":\"5000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"15\\\"\",\"price\":\"500000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"17\\\"\",\"price\":\"700000.00\"}},{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"22\\\"\",\"price\":\"900000.00\"}}],\"conditions\":[]}]"
```

As you see in my `attributes` part I have nested array such as :

```
\"attributes\":[{\"attr\":{\"label\":\"Gray\",\"price\":\"7000.00\"}},....
```

here is where I get that `label` and `price` in my function loop.

If I use loop such as:

```
foreach($request->attr as $subs) {
  array_push($customAttributes, [
   'attr' => [
    'label' => $subs->title,
    'price' => $subs->price,
    ]
]);
```

Instead of what I have I will get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

on this line:

```
  'attr' => [
    'label' => $subs->title,
    'price' => $subs->price,
```

PS:
If I use `$customAttributes = $request->attr;` with my own loop (at the top) I will get `id` of selected option only, which is no good to me.

Comment: Dont forget to add multiple to yor select tag and your options should be in the request.Check my answer.

Comment: FYI, if you like, this `$product = Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();` can be written as `$product = Product::findOrFail($id);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you called your product's `suboptions` relationship instead of getting it from the request.
You are calling it with this `$product->suboptions` instead of getting it from the request.

```
$customAttributes = $request->attr; // try to dd($customAttributes) so you can see it
```

UPDATE:

You only need to pass the id to your options

```
<select name="attr[]" class="form-control" multiple>
   <option value="">Select</option>
   @foreach($optioncollection as $suboption)
     <option value="{{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

and in your Controller, fetch them and validate

```
public function addingItem(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    $customAttributes = [];
    if (!empty($request->attr)) {
        foreach ($request->attr as $sub) {
            // You should fetch the price from the database NOT from the user 
            //   request as it will be very vulnerable to attacks

            // find the suboption
            $sub = Suboption::find($sub); // Here I assume you have the Model 
                                    // for your Product's suboptions
            if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                array_push($customAttributes, [
                    'attr' => [
                        'label' => $sub->title,
                        'price' => $sub->price,
                    ]
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $customAttributes,
    ));

    Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: returns `null`.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'` but i can't find it! seems all closed and nothing extra!

Comment: found it! the result `[]`

Comment: what can you get when you `dd($request->attr)` when you have selected options?

Comment: `array:2 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
]`

Comment: `$suboption` in the `<select>` tag could be the cause. What can you get if you `dd($suboption)` on your blade file?

Comment: i get nothing on `dd($suboption)` ! but i do have my options without dd! strange :)    https://ibb.co/gteYob

Comment: can you check `dd($optioncollection)`, maybe your `$suboption` doesn't have an `id` attribute? because it returned `null` on the controller.

Comment: none of them return nothing! but i get what i need without `dd` how come? :))

Comment: ok my bad! i placed the code in wrong part i have dd on optioncollection

Comment: because I think you put `dd` inside the `<select>` tag. try it outside the tag

Comment: This is much better +1

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you get the options from an order or The Request and not from the Prodect ?!
Because the product should obviously have all options.
...........

-Edit:1

Change your loop like this

```
foreach($request->attr as $subs)
```

and change your selct tag to look something like this

```
<select multiple>
```

-Edit2

After editing your question, I think you have two options:

1. use the id  from each $subs to query your suboptions again from the DB

OR

2. Serialize the title and price in the front end html option tag so that you will end up with something like this:

   ```
   <option   value="{{$suboption->title.','.$suboption->price}}" .....> .....</option>
   ```

then inside your loop do like this:

```
foreach($request->attr as $subs) {
    $title_and_price = explode(',', $subs);
    array_push($customAttributes, [
    'attr' => [
    'label' => $title_and_price[0],
     'price' => $title_and_price[1]
   ]
]);
```

-Edit:3

We should also add square brackets to the name in the select tag like this:

```
  <select name="{{ $optiontitle }}[]"  multiple>
```

Edit:4 I found another problem:

you should use name = "{{ $optiontitle }}[]" in the select because they canot all have the same name thus, you have to make the name attribute of the select tag dynamic as well

Comment: I add product and its options to cart and cart info (include all that) to order table. then i'll have complete order.  where did you see people add product to order and then edit that order to add options?!

Comment: but you should get them first from the Request object.Try my edited answer

Comment: ok there is the issue: with my loop I can get title and price as I need that. with your loop I only get `id`s which is not useful to me. I will update my question.

Comment: well, any idea?

Comment: base on solution no.2 i get `A non-numeric value encountered`

Comment: on this `<option   value="{{$suboption->title+','+$suboption->price}}" .....> .....</option>`

Comment: title is not numeric

Comment: replace the plus sign with a dot. value="{{$suboption->title.','.$suboption->price}}" or somthing like this

Comment: `Array to string conversion` on `'label' => $title_and_price[0],
               'price' => $$title_and_price[1]`

Comment: I found the problem! I have several option as it is dynamic, if i only choose one of them eg(color) and not choose(size) i will get offset error but if i choose both it will return values. what do you think?

Comment: we forgot to add square brackets to the name in the select to tell PHP that this is an array because of the multiple.chech my edited answer

Comment: i've already done that. the issue is if i only select 1 option OR even none selected

Comment: perhaps you should check if it is set by using the isset() function or something similar and since your mean problem is solved you may accept the answer.

Comment: bro my main problem is getting this to work which still i get error :) where should i add `isset` ?

Comment: you should use name = "{{ $optiontitle }}[0]" . Check my edited answer.

Comment: solved bro. thanks for your helps. i will vote up you.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing *Controller Function **addingItem*** with below

```
public function addingItem(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $product = Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

      $customAttributes = [];
      if(!empty($product->suboptions)){
          foreach($product->suboptions as $subs) {
              array_push($customAttributes, [
                  'attr' => [
                      'label' => $subs->title,
                      'price' => $subs->price,
                  ]
              ]);
          }
      }
      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $request->input('attr'), // Attributes Array
      ));
      Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I assume you need to insert multiple attributes by

> @foreach($options as $optiontitle => $optioncollection)

replace the blade code,

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($options as $optiontitle => $optioncollection)
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $optiontitle }}</td>
    <td class="text-left">
      <select name="attr" class="form-control">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       @foreach($optioncollection as $suboption)
         <option value="{{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}</option>
       @endforeach
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

with below

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($options as $optiontitle => $optioncollection)
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $optiontitle }}</td>
    <td class="text-left">
      <select name="attr[]" class="form-control">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       @foreach($optioncollection as $suboption)
         <option value="{{$suboption->id}}">{{$suboption->title}} - {{ number_format($suboption->price, 0) }}</option>
       @endforeach
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

it will create an attribute array which will prevent the error,

> Trying to get property of non-object

If you need further assistance, leave a comment.